# Saving client data to storage optimization

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, dom-events

I'm implementing sort of Google spreadsheet (or very similar functionality) and I found that it's not easy to make it really fluent when I need to save data to database.

I have html+js table which takes user input in cell and recalculates following cells automatically on client side. This works really fluent since I don't perform any backend calls upon editing.

But I need to implement autosave for user data. Right now I see several ways to do that:

- perform autosave based on was table edited or not, checking table state each 5 (other number) seconds
- perform autosave on leaving page using `window.onbeforeunload` event.

The problem of the 1st way is that it will cause real slowdown for user as far as I can see. The problem of second way is that it's not really reliable.
Are there any other ways/tips to implement autosave? Maybe other events?

Another issue I have is what data to store exactly: only changed cells (requires more complicated algorithm but can be done) or it's okay to save the whole table document at once since I'm using graph database (MongoDB)?

Comment: You could maybe use localStorage or SessionStorage for autosaving,..

Comment: @Keith, thank you very much, since I'm amateur and self learner, I never thought in that way. I will look at it. I think it's really helpfull.